# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I'm learning reactjs. I want to get result from fuction findTenloaidv(id) when load list bpdvList but error**

```
    async componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        const bangphi = await (await fetch(`/gvnhanh/bangphidv/`)).json();
        this.setState({
                bpdvs: bangphi,
                isLoading: false,
            })
    }

    async findTenloaidv(id){
        const loaidv = await (await fetch(`/gvnhanh/loaidv/${id}`)).json();
        
        return loaidv.tenloai
    }

render(){

        const {bpdvs, isLoading} = this.state;

        const bpdvList = bpdvs.map(bpdv =>{
            return <tr key={bpdv.idbpdv}>
                        <td className="text-center">{bpdv.iddv}</td>
                        <td className="text-center">{this.findTenloaidv(bpdv.idloaidv)}</td>
                        <td className="text-center">{bpdv.tendv}</td>
                        <td className="text-center">{bpdv.mota}</td>
                        <td className="text-center">{this.currencyFormat(bpdv.gia)}</td>
                        <td className="text-center">{bpdv.donvitinh}</td>
                    </tr>

        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple errors here.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    const bangphi = await (await fetch(`/gvnhanh/bangphidv/`)).json(); // Here
    const bangphi = await fetch('Your endpoint') //await your fetch data
    const data = await bangphi.json()  // Then convert to json
    this.setState({
            bpdvs: data.bangphi, // changed here
            isLoading: false,
        })
}
// Change this to match 
async findTenloaidv(id){
    const loaidv = await (await fetch(`/gvnhanh/loaidv/${id}`)).json();
    
    return loaidv.tenloai
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

> `<td className="text-center">{this.findTenloaidv(bpdv.idloaidv)}</td>`

`findTenloaidv` method returns a `promise` as it is `async` which is type of object`([object Promise])`. That's why react throws this error `Objects are not valid as a React child`.

You need to map the currency format while you're fetching data. Try like this

```
async componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    const bangphi = await (await fetch(`/gvnhanh/bangphidv/`)).json(); // Here
    const bangphi = await fetch('Your endpoint') //await your fetch data
    const data = await bangphi.json()  // Then convert to json
    const bpdvs = data.bangphi.map(async bpdv => {
       const loaidv = await this.findTenloaidv(bpdv.idloaidv)
       return {
         ...bpdv,
         idloaidv: loaidv.tenloai
       }
    })
    this.setState({
            bpdvs,
            isLoading: false,
        })
}
```

```
   ...
    <td className="text-center">{bpdv.iddv}</td>
    <td className="text-center">{bpdv.idloaidv}</td>
   ....
```